# How to get the status of the rsyslog connection with the server on the client side?

Tags: rsyslog

I am currently using rsyslog to send messages to my server.

I am trying to know the status of the connection with my server. I saw that there was a plugin "impstats" ([stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402096/how-to-verify-rsyslog-tcp-communication-with-the-server-from-the-client-side)) but it does not give me the information I'm looking for.

For information:
rsyslog: 8.25.0
librelp: 1.2.12

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command for verification:

```
sudo netstat -taupn | grep syslog
```

If you see an entry with the status `ESTABLISHED` , you are connected to the server.